# Git push heroku master fails django

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django application on heroku.

Here is my proc file:

```
web: gunicorn playlist.wsgi --log-file -
```

Here is my requirments.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.9.6
gunicorn==19.5.0
whitenoise==3.0
```

Here is the error messege on `git push heroku master`

```
Counting objects: 191, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (173/173), done.
Writing objects: 100% (191/191), 105.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 191 (delta 91), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/python
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/python
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shielded-fortress-12681.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-fortress-12681.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-fortress-12681.git'
```

### EDIT

I have also tried:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

Comment: Did you look at the more info link?

Comment: Yes I did went through it. I updated it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was putting the `Procfile` in the wrong place. It should be at the root of your repository.